# Overwrite data in table A if data present in table B, + map to own overwritten data if foreign key to other ID present

Tags: mysql, database

We have 2 tables which provide a list of schools.

The first table (`school_data`) is the original data from a public database, which gets updated when new data is released by the government.

The second table `school_data_overwrites` has most of the same fields, and is used to correct typos and inaccuracies in the first table (it's in a separate table to be able to update the data while keeping our edits).

We then use a view which our code should query, which for each row should show the value from `school_data_overwrites` if present, or fallback to `school_data` if not present. What's challenging is that on top of that some rows have a `parent_school_id` which links to another row, which itself could have overwritten data.

We got to the following view, but it's extremely slow and uses a lot of CPU:

```sql
SELECT
    school_data.id AS id,
    school_data.ref_id AS ref_id,
    school_data.schoolyear AS schoolyear,

    IF(school_data_overwrites.type <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.type <> NULL, school_data_overwrites.type, school_data.type) AS type,
    IF(school_data_overwrites.name <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.name <> NULL, school_data_overwrites.name, school_data.name) AS name,
    IF(school_data_overwrites.email <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.email <> NULL, school_data_overwrites.email, school_data.email) AS email,
    IF(school_data_overwrites.certified_email <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.certified_email <> NULL,  school_data_overwrites.certified_email, school_data.certified_email) AS certified_email,
    IF(school_data_overwrites.website <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.website <> NULL, school_data_overwrites.website,  school_data.website) AS website,
    IF(school_data_overwrites.address <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.address <> NULL, school_data_overwrites.address, school_data.address) AS address,
    IF(school_data_overwrites.postcode <> '' OR school_data_overwrites.postcode <> NULL,  school_data_overwrites.postcode, school_data.postcode) AS postcode,

    school_data.city_id AS city_id,
    school_data.city_name AS city_name,
    school_data.province_id AS province_id,
    school_data.province_name AS province_name,
    school_data.province_iso_code AS province_iso_code,
    school_data.region_id AS region_id,
    school_data.region_name AS region_name,
    school_data.nuts3_2010_code AS nuts3_2010_code,

    school_data_overwrites.facebook_url AS facebook_url,
    school_data_overwrites.twitter_url AS twitter_url,
    school_data_overwrites.vip AS vip,

    school_data.parent_school_id AS parent_school_id,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.city_id, '') parent_school_ref_id,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.city_id, '') parent_school_schoolyear,

    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.type <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.type <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.type, parent_school_data.type),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_type,
    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.name <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.name <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.name, parent_school_data.name),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_name,
    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.email <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.email <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.email, parent_school_data.email),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_email,
    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.certified_email <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.certified_email <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.certified_email, parent_school_data.certified_email),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_certified_email,
    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.website <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.website <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.website, parent_school_data.website),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_website,
    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.address <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.address <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.address, parent_school_data.address),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_address,
    IF(
        school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL,
        IF(parent_school_data_overwrites.postcode <> '' OR parent_school_data_overwrites.postcode <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.postcode, parent_school_data.postcode),
                ''
    ) AS parent_school_postcode,

    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.city_id, '') AS parent_school_city_id,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.city_name, '') AS parent_school_city_name,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.province_id, '') AS parent_school_province_id,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.province_name, '') AS parent_school_province_name,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.province_iso_code, '') AS parent_school_province_iso_code,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.region_id, '') AS parent_school_region_id,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.region_name, '') AS parent_school_region_name,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data.nuts3_2010_code, '') AS parent_school_nuts3_2010_code,

    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.facebook_url, '') AS parent_school_facebook_url,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.twitter_url, '') AS parent_school_twitter_url,
    IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL, parent_school_data_overwrites.vip, '') AS parent_school_vip
FROM
    school_data LEFT JOIN school_data_overwrites ON school_data_overwrites.school_id = school_data.id,
    school_data parent_school_data LEFT JOIN school_data_overwrites parent_school_data_overwrites ON parent_school_data_overwrites.school_id = parent_school_data.parent_school_id
WHERE parent_school_data.id = school_data.id;
```

`school_data` looks like this:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ref_id                          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| schoolyear                      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| type                            | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| name                            | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| email                           | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| certified_email                 | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| website                         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| address                         | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cad_code                        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| postcode                        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| city_name                       | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| city_id                         | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| province_name                   | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| province_id                     | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| province_iso_code               | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| region_name                     | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| region_id                       | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| nuts3_2010_code                 | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| parent_school_id                | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
```

This is `school_data_overwrites`:

```
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| school_id                 | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| type                      | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name                      | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| email                     | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| certified_email           | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| website                   | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address                   | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| postcode                  | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| city_id                   | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| facebook_url              | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| twitter_url               | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email_they_read           | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| certified_email_they_read | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| vip                       | tinyint(4)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created_at                | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at                | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

We have no idea how to optimize it. I think we're including too many conditions, and there's an easier way.

How can we make this view more performant?

Comment: Isn't the condition `IF(school_data.parent_school_id <> '' OR school_data.parent_school_id <> NULL [...]` always true?

Comment: No, not all schools have a parent school

Comment: Yes, but `parent_school_id` will always be one of `different from ''` or `different from NULL`

Comment: My bad, this actually seems to work, see [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0013/1)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. When it's NULL it won't be one of those, right..? In ~ 20,000 cases it's null, ~40,000 has an ID in it

Comment: Ah, yes it works. Our problem is just that it's extremely slow and uses a lot of CPU.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192072/discussion-between-steve-t-and-nkkollaw).